# If $_POST value has the word AND, then insert word ARE

Tags: php, if-statement, insert, field

I have a typical question, I'm not sure whether it is possible or not. I have a form in which there is a field namely Producer. How do I make it possible, if user use the word **and** in the field then insert the word **are** in the result, and if user don't use the word **and** in the field then insert the word **is** in the result. Let me explain you with an example.

Example (the word **and** is in the field) then generate the following result:

ABC **and** DEF **are** the producers of the movie.

Example (the word **and** is NOT in the field) then generate the following result:

XYZ **is** the producer of the movie.

I have the following code:

```
if(!empty($_POST['Producer'])) {
$description .= ' ' . $_POST["Producer"] . ' is/are the producer(s) of the movie';
}
```

Kindly tell me if anyone have the idea.

Comment: Seems simple enough, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!empty($_POST['Producer']))
{
    if(stripos($_POST['Producer'], ' and ') != false) // ' and ' is found
        $producers = $_POST['Producer'] .' are the producers ';
    else
        $producers = $_POST['Producer'] .' is the producer ';

    $description = $producers .'of the movie';
}
```

I put `' and '` instead of `'and'` (with whitespaces) because some names contains the word 'are', so it would return true even if there's only one name.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use **(!empty** with **(strpos**? because if the field of Producer is left empty then it should not display that whole line.

Comment: very important point here and in @Bandic00t 's answer: it should be `' and '` with spaces, to prevent matches vs 'Branderson' etc... further, consider using strtolower() to match 'and', 'AND'...

Comment: @cypherabe I put with spaces and noticed why I did that, see my answer better. I've changed `strpos` to `stripos`. It's now case-insensitive :)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Another thing if I want to check multiple words e.g. **and**, **or**, **comma**, it should check first word **and** it it doesn't exist then check next word **or** if it also not exist then check character **comma** then parse the value. How to do it?

Comment: Before you start making some more complex applications, you should learn the basics. Like formatting `if` statements.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I think I've made it more complex for you but Thanks for your help so far. I have a little knowledge of these functions and I tried this `if((stripos($_POST['Producer'], ' and ')) || (stripos($_POST['Producer'], ' or ')) != false)` and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Simply call `strpos` with `$_POST['Producer']` as haystack and `and` as needle. If the return value is false, the string doesn't contain `and`.

Now you can depending on the return value create your output.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: This.  Build it into an if statement like `if(strpos($_POST['Producer'],'and') !== false){ $verb = 'are'} else {$verb = 'is'}`

Answer (score 2):

Below code should work (not tested).

```
if(!empty($_POST['Producer'])) {
    $producer = $_POST["Producer"]; // CONSIDER SANITIZING
    $pos = stripos($_POST['Producer'], ' and ');
    list($verb, $pl) = $pos ? array('are', 's') : array('is', '');
    $description .= " $producer $verb the producer$pl of the movie";
}
```

As noted you should also consider sanitizing the incoming value of $_POST["Producer"], depending on how you intend to use the formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but something along the lines of this should work.

```
$string = $_POST['Producer'];

//This is the case if the user used and.
$start = strstr($string, 'and');
if($start != null)
{
    $newString = substr($string, 0, $start) . "are" . substr($string, $start+3, strlen($string))
}
```